# fit a raising curve started from zero and end in one

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have two curves and I want to fit two curves on each of them; I fitted the first one (a decaying curve starting from 1 and ends 0) using this function exp(-1/b *x). However, I have a problem with fitting the second curve which is a rising curve starting from zero and ending in 1. Can everyone please help me out with a function that can fit the second curve while I can calculate the relaxation time constant of my raising curve using that function?

[image]

Also the corresponded data are here: the first column is time, and the second and third columns are related to the decaying and raising curves, respectively.

Time    Decaying Curve  Raising Curve
0.0000  1.0000  0.0000
0.1000  0.9900  0.0100
0.2000  0.9802  0.0198
0.3000  0.9704  0.0296
0.4000  0.9608  0.0392
0.5000  0.9512  0.0488
0.6000  0.9418  0.0582
0.7000  0.9324  0.0676
0.8000  0.9231  0.0769
0.9000  0.9139  0.0861
1.0000  0.9048  0.0952
1.1000  0.8958  0.1042
1.2000  0.8869  0.1131
1.3000  0.8781  0.1219
1.4000  0.8694  0.1306
1.5000  0.8607  0.1393
1.6000  0.8521  0.1479
1.7000  0.8437  0.1563
1.8000  0.8353  0.1647
1.9000  0.8270  0.1730
2.0000  0.8187  0.1813
2.1000  0.8106  0.1894
2.2000  0.8025  0.1975
2.3000  0.7945  0.2055
2.4000  0.7866  0.2134
2.5000  0.7788  0.2212
2.6000  0.7711  0.2289
2.7000  0.7634  0.2366
2.8000  0.7558  0.2442
2.9000  0.7483  0.2517
3.0000  0.7408  0.2592
3.1000  0.7334  0.2666
3.2000  0.7261  0.2739
3.3000  0.7189  0.2811
3.4000  0.7118  0.2882
3.5000  0.7047  0.2953
3.6000  0.6977  0.3023
3.7000  0.6907  0.3093
3.8000  0.6839  0.3161
3.9000  0.6771  0.3229
4.0000  0.6703  0.3297
4.1000  0.6637  0.3363
4.2000  0.6570  0.3430
4.3000  0.6505  0.3495
4.4000  0.6440  0.3560
4.5000  0.6376  0.3624
4.6000  0.6313  0.3687
4.7000  0.6250  0.3750
4.8000  0.6188  0.3812
4.9000  0.6126  0.3874
5.0000  0.6065  0.3935
5.1000  0.6005  0.3995
5.2000  0.5945  0.4055
5.3000  0.5886  0.4114
5.4000  0.5827  0.4173
5.5000  0.5769  0.4231
5.6000  0.5712  0.4288
5.7000  0.5655  0.4345
5.8000  0.5599  0.4401
5.9000  0.5543  0.4457
6.0000  0.5488  0.4512
6.1000  0.5434  0.4566
6.2000  0.5379  0.4621
6.3000  0.5326  0.4674
6.4000  0.5273  0.4727
6.5000  0.5220  0.4780
6.6000  0.5169  0.4831
6.7000  0.5117  0.4883
6.8000  0.5066  0.4934
6.9000  0.5016  0.4984
7.0000  0.4966  0.5034
7.1000  0.4916  0.5084
7.2000  0.4868  0.5132
7.3000  0.4819  0.5181
7.4000  0.4771  0.5229
7.5000  0.4724  0.5276
7.6000  0.4677  0.5323
7.7000  0.4630  0.5370
7.8000  0.4584  0.5416
7.9000  0.4538  0.5462
8.0000  0.4493  0.5507
8.1000  0.4449  0.5551
8.2000  0.4404  0.5596
8.3000  0.4360  0.5640
8.4000  0.4317  0.5683
8.5000  0.4274  0.5726
8.6000  0.4232  0.5768
8.7000  0.4190  0.5810
8.8000  0.4148  0.5852
8.9000  0.4107  0.5893
9.0000  0.4066  0.5934
9.1000  0.4025  0.5975
9.2000  0.3985  0.6015
9.3000  0.3946  0.6054
9.4000  0.3906  0.6094
9.5000  0.3867  0.6133
9.6000  0.3829  0.6171
9.7000  0.3791  0.6209
9.8000  0.3753  0.6247
9.9000  0.3716  0.6284
10.0000 0.3679  0.6321

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems pretty trivial - there is so little error in the data that it appears artificially constructed, which is suspicious. Either that's been done for the purposes of demonstration, or in your application "the left hand isn't talking to the right hand" and a parameter isn't being passed from one place to another properly.

Assuming good faith, your fits are essentially "perfect" and your curves are essentially exact vertical reflections of each other; and the estimate I show is essentially equal to the fit parameter:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

time, decaying, raising = np.array((
    0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000, 0.1000, 0.9900, 0.0100, 0.2000, 0.9802, 0.0198, 0.3000, 0.9704, 0.0296, 0.4000, 0.9608,
    0.0392, 0.5000, 0.9512, 0.0488, 0.6000, 0.9418, 0.0582, 0.7000, 0.9324, 0.0676, 0.8000, 0.9231, 0.0769, 0.9000,
    0.9139, 0.0861, 1.0000, 0.9048, 0.0952, 1.1000, 0.8958, 0.1042, 1.2000, 0.8869, 0.1131, 1.3000, 0.8781, 0.1219,
    1.4000, 0.8694, 0.1306, 1.5000, 0.8607, 0.1393, 1.6000, 0.8521, 0.1479, 1.7000, 0.8437, 0.1563, 1.8000, 0.8353,
    0.1647, 1.9000, 0.8270, 0.1730, 2.0000, 0.8187, 0.1813, 2.1000, 0.8106, 0.1894, 2.2000, 0.8025, 0.1975, 2.3000,
    0.7945, 0.2055, 2.4000, 0.7866, 0.2134, 2.5000, 0.7788, 0.2212, 2.6000, 0.7711, 0.2289, 2.7000, 0.7634, 0.2366,
    2.8000, 0.7558, 0.2442, 2.9000, 0.7483, 0.2517, 3.0000, 0.7408, 0.2592, 3.1000, 0.7334, 0.2666, 3.2000, 0.7261,
    0.2739, 3.3000, 0.7189, 0.2811, 3.4000, 0.7118, 0.2882, 3.5000, 0.7047, 0.2953, 3.6000, 0.6977, 0.3023, 3.7000,
    0.6907, 0.3093, 3.8000, 0.6839, 0.3161, 3.9000, 0.6771, 0.3229, 4.0000, 0.6703, 0.3297, 4.1000, 0.6637, 0.3363,
    4.2000, 0.6570, 0.3430, 4.3000, 0.6505, 0.3495, 4.4000, 0.6440, 0.3560, 4.5000, 0.6376, 0.3624, 4.6000, 0.6313,
    0.3687, 4.7000, 0.6250, 0.3750, 4.8000, 0.6188, 0.3812, 4.9000, 0.6126, 0.3874, 5.0000, 0.6065, 0.3935, 5.1000,
    0.6005, 0.3995, 5.2000, 0.5945, 0.4055, 5.3000, 0.5886, 0.4114, 5.4000, 0.5827, 0.4173, 5.5000, 0.5769, 0.4231,
    5.6000, 0.5712, 0.4288, 5.7000, 0.5655, 0.4345, 5.8000, 0.5599, 0.4401, 5.9000, 0.5543, 0.4457, 6.0000, 0.5488,
    0.4512, 6.1000, 0.5434, 0.4566, 6.2000, 0.5379, 0.4621, 6.3000, 0.5326, 0.4674, 6.4000, 0.5273, 0.4727, 6.5000,
    0.5220, 0.4780, 6.6000, 0.5169, 0.4831, 6.7000, 0.5117, 0.4883, 6.8000, 0.5066, 0.4934, 6.9000, 0.5016, 0.4984,
    7.0000, 0.4966, 0.5034, 7.1000, 0.4916, 0.5084, 7.2000, 0.4868, 0.5132, 7.3000, 0.4819, 0.5181, 7.4000, 0.4771,
    0.5229, 7.5000, 0.4724, 0.5276, 7.6000, 0.4677, 0.5323, 7.7000, 0.4630, 0.5370, 7.8000, 0.4584, 0.5416, 7.9000,
    0.4538, 0.5462, 8.0000, 0.4493, 0.5507, 8.1000, 0.4449, 0.5551, 8.2000, 0.4404, 0.5596, 8.3000, 0.4360, 0.5640,
    8.4000, 0.4317, 0.5683, 8.5000, 0.4274, 0.5726, 8.6000, 0.4232, 0.5768, 8.7000, 0.4190, 0.5810, 8.8000, 0.4148,
    0.5852, 8.9000, 0.4107, 0.5893, 9.0000, 0.4066, 0.5934, 9.1000, 0.4025, 0.5975, 9.2000, 0.3985, 0.6015, 9.3000,
    0.3946, 0.6054, 9.4000, 0.3906, 0.6094, 9.5000, 0.3867, 0.6133, 9.6000, 0.3829, 0.6171, 9.7000, 0.3791, 0.6209,
    9.8000, 0.3753, 0.6247, 9.9000, 0.3716, 0.6284, 10.0000, 0.3679, 0.6321
)).reshape((-1, 3)).T


def decay_model(x: np.ndarray, b: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.exp(-x/b)


def raise_model(x: np.ndarray, b: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return 1 - np.exp(-x/b)

b_est_decay = -time[-1] / np.log(decaying[-1])
b_est_raise = -time[-1] / np.log(1 - raising[-1])
(b_decay,), _ = curve_fit(f=decay_model, xdata=time, ydata=decaying, p0=b_est_decay)
(b_raise,), _ = curve_fit(f=raise_model, xdata=time, ydata=raising, p0=b_est_raise)
print('b (decay) =', b_decay)
print('b (raise) =', b_raise)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(time, decaying, label='decay (experiment)')
ax.plot(time, raising, label='raise (experiment)')
ax.plot(time, decay_model(time, b_decay), label='decay (fit)', linestyle='--')
ax.plot(time, raise_model(time, b_raise), label='raise (fit)', linestyle='--')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

```
b (decay) = 9.999933984880915
b (raise) = 9.999933984878394
```

[image: fit]